# Split a polygon by another polygon and remove the overlapping area

Tags: polygon, geometry, dotspatial

Using DotSpatial I want to split a polygon by another overlapping polygon. The overlapped area can be clipped using the Intersection method but I did not find any way to split the original source polygon and remove the overlapping area.
[image: Orginal polygon is split into another three polygons]

Comment: DotSpatial probably has some sort of Difference function that does the same thing as https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html.

Comment: @user30184 you are right! DotSpatial has some Difference function. But they only return a single feature. Now I found a library in which "Difference" function is fulfilling my requirements.